# perform lookup on array from another collection in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of `Orders`. each order has a list of Items, and each Item has catalog_id, which is  an `ObjectId` pointing to the `Catalogs` collection.
I need an aggregate query that will retrieve certain orders - each order with its Items in extended fashion including the Catalog `name` and `SKU`. i.e:

Original data structure:

```
Orders: [{
 _id : ObjectId('ord1'),
items : [{
   catalog_id: ObjectId('xyz1'),
   qty: 5
},
{
   catalog_id: ObjectId('xyz2'),
   qty: 3
}]
Catalogs: [{
 _id : ObjectId('xyz1') 
name: 'my catalog name',
SKU: 'XxYxZx1'
},{
 _id : ObjectId('xyz2') 
name: 'my other catalog name',
SKU: 'XxYxZx2'
}
]
```

ideal outcome would be:

```
Orders: [{
 _id : ObjectId('ord1'),
items : [{
   catalog_id: ObjectId('xyz1'),
   catalog_name: 'my catalog name',
   catalog_SKU: 'XxYxZx1' , 
   qty: 5
},
{
   catalog_id: ObjectId('xyz2'),
   catalog_name: 'my other catalog name',
   catalog_SKU: 'XxYxZx2' , 
   qty: 3
}
]
```

What I did so far was:

```
db.orders.aggregate(
    [
    {
        $match: {merchant_order_id: 'NIM333'}
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
          from: "catalogs",
          //localField: 'items.catalog_id',
          //foreignField: '_id',
          let: { 'catalogId' : 'items.catalog_id' },
          pipeline: [
              {
                $match : {$expr:{$eq:["$catalogs._id", "$$catalogId"]}}
              },
              {
                  $project: {"name": 1, "merchant_SKU": 1 }
              }
          ],
          as: "items_ex"
        },
    },
])
```

but `items_ex` comes out empty for some reason i cannot understand.

Comment: the localField and foreignField option does work, but retrieves the entire Catalog object, and I would like to project it, so I have to pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a dollar sign when you define your pipeline variable. There should be:

```
let: { 'catalogId' : '$items.catalog_id' },
```

and also this expression returns an array to you need [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/index.html) instead of `$eq`:

```
{
    $lookup: {
    from: "catalogs",
    let: { 'catalogId' : 'items.catalog_id' },
    pipeline: [
        {
            $match : {$expr:{$in:["$_id", "$$catalogId"]}}
        },
        {
            $project: {"name": 1, "merchant_SKU": 1 }
        }
    ],
    as: "items_ex"
    }
}
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ux97UfLXU0v)

Comment: I did your two proposed corrections, but it still returns an empty items_ex array

Comment: @Nimrod please try lowercase `catalogs` as collection name

Comment: @Nimrod could you compare your code with Mongo Playground ?

Comment: Works perfectly on the playground, doesn't work on my server. could it be because i'm on 4.01, and playground is 4.2.2?
Additionally, how do I project the quantity as well? I tried to project it and got an array of all the quantities...

Comment: Try to check if all the fields names are the same. I didn't change much from your example (just converted `_id` to be strings in this example)

Comment: Ok, I hope I'll manage, but the problem with quantity returning an array instead of the record's value remains...

Comment: @Nimrod try this way: https://mongoplayground.net/p/tc-19O4U8yt

Answer (score 1):

You need to first [**`$unwind`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the `items` and reconstruct the array back using [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) to match the exact position of `qty` with the `catalogs_id` inside the `items` array

```
db.orders.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "merchant_order_id": "NIM333" }},
  { "$unwind": "$items" },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "catalogs",
    "let": { "catalogId": "$items.catalog_id", "qty": "$items.qty" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": ["$_id", "$$catalogId"] } }},
      { "$project": { "name": 1, "merchant_SKU": 1, "qty": "$$qty" }}
    ],
    "as": "items"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$items" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "items": { "$push": "$items" },
    "data": { "$first": "$$ROOT" }
  }},
  { "$replaceRoot": {
    "newRoot": {
      "$mergeObjects": ["$data", { "items": "$items" }]
    }
  }}
])
```

[**MongoPlayground**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9bYV57NabL6)

Comment: very nice, thanks. I wanted to avoid unwinding, but it looks solid.

Comment: One more way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54617074/mongodb-lookup-when-foreign-field-is-an-array-of-objects

Comment: The problem with this is that it becomes an inner join, which means that every order without items disappears... this is why unwind/group is not the way to go i think

Comment: What do you mean by *order without items disappears*? You can always maintain the order when using `$unwind` and `$group`

Comment: Yes, you are right, I saw the option to keep nulls in $unwind. thanks.