# How to lookup and match multiple keys in array of objects Mongodb?

Tags: mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm using MongoDB, and I tried to do it with many pipeline steps but I couldn't find a way.

I have a `team_squads` collection, where a document looks like this with an array `players` that contain objects where a players is present in one of the objects.

```
    {
        "seasonId": 363,
        "seasonLabel": "2020/21",
        "teamId": 1,
        "players": [
            {
                "appearances": 12,
                "p_id": 4985
            },
            ....
        ]
    },
```

I have a pipeline from an other collection that returns the following

```
  {
    totalPlaytime: 1058,
    averagePasses: 58.52551984877127,
    name: 'Mateusz Klich',
    id: 13089,
    seasonId: 363,
    appearances: 12,
    averagePlaytime: 88.16666666666667
  }
```

What I want to do is get the field `teamId` and `appearances` by matching `id` with `p_id` and matching `seasonId`. How can this be done, I'm having not been successful in creating a pipeline that does this.

The expected result is,

```
  {
    totalPlaytime: 1058,
    averagePasses: 58.52551984877127,
    name: 'Mateusz Klich',
    id: 13089,
    seasonId: 363,
    appearances: 12,
    averagePlaytime: 88.16666666666667
    appearances: 12,
    teamId: 1,
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Found answer in an other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54617074/mongodb-lookup-when-foreign-field-is-an-array-of-objects) where the trick is to match the top level field first and unwind the array of interest before matching the field in the array.
Below is the pipeline.

```
    .lookup({
        'from': 'team_squads',
        'let': {'id': '$id', 'seasonId': '$seasonId'},
        'pipeline': [
            { '$match': {"$expr": { '$eq': [ "$seasonId", "$$seasonId" ] } } },
            { "$unwind": "$players" },
            { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": ["$players.p_id", "$$id"] } } },
         ],
        'as': 'player_stats'
    })
    .unwind(
        'player_stats'
    )
    .project({
        'totalPlaytime': 1,
        'total_pass': 1,
        'averagePasses': 1,
        'name': 1,
        'id': 1,
        'seasonId': 1,
        'teamId': '$player_stats.teamId',
        'teamName': '$player_stats.teamName',
        'appearances': '$player_stats.players.appearances',
        '_id': 0
    })
```